# Google maps is not showing location details through Static Map API as it normally does

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have been working with Google Static Map API for a location map project. During my work, I found that the regular Google map (maps.google.com) is showing a lot of details in the map while the same coordinates search reveals a Static Map with only a few of the details.

Have a look at the differences:

From maps.google.com site:-

Search coordinates: 23.726927,90.415785

From maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap API:-

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=23.726927,90.415785&zoom=16&size=500x500&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7C%7C23.726927,90.415785&sensor=false&style=feature:all%7Celement:all&visual_refresh=true

Out of these two maps, the latter one is showing few details compared to first one. You can see that some of the bank locations are not pointed, a hockey stadium is not listed, etc. in the static map api while the regular map accurately labels them.

My question is why the difference? How can we get the detailed map through Static Map API?

Comment: Just want to let you know that I'm having the same issue with my staticmaps that all used to work.